# Redundancy in the MonadWriter class

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have been reading the documentation for the [MonadWriter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Strict.html#g:1) class, and I see that `writer` and `tell` can be written in terms of each other. It seems to me that if the class methods behave as the documentation describes, then `pass` can be written in terms of `tell` and `listen`:

```
pass :: m (a, w -> w) -> m a
pass m = do
    ((a, f), w) <- listen m
    tell $ f w
    return a
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ends up writing `w <> f w`, but it should write `f w`.

```
ghci
> import Control.Monad.Writer as W
> :{
pass m = do
  ((a, f), w) <- listen m
  tell (f w)
  return a
:}
> pass (writer ((0, map (+ 10)), [1])) :: Writer [Integer] Int
WriterT (Identity (0,[1,11]))
> W.pass (writer ((0, map (+ 10)), [1])) :: Writer [Integer] Int
WriterT (Identity (0,[11]))
```